# Forcing page numbers with IEEEtran

Tags: page-numbering, ieeetran

The `IEEEtran` document class is hiding page numbers from my document! Is it possible to force page numbers to appear in the document?

EDIT: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am using conference mode!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. A simple test I did shows the page numbers.

Comment: If you used the _conference mode_, automatically headings and page numbers are not displayed.

Comment: Where do you want the page numbers located? In the header, or the footer? Centered or at the outer margin?

Comment: anywhere :) It's just for doing revisions on paper and referencing pages.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Put this right after `\maketitle`:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Adding your suggestion in the document preamble creates page numbers from the first page onward.

Comment: Not if \maketitle is used on the first page :/

Comment: Perfect! You got it! I just wish that it worked on page 1, but it's no big. Thank you!

Comment: @Sandro: In order to have a page number on the first page *with* `\maketitle`, include `\g@addto@macro\maketitle{\thispagestyle{plain}}` between `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`. This is just the easiest, even though there are other page styles.

Comment: @Werner Cool tip, any idea how to get things to show up in \@oddhead on the first page?

Comment: This is not working for me. Any idea why? I put the code right after \begin{document}

Comment: @sanatana [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background. ...

Comment: @sanatana ... To make your question answerable, you'll need to provide more detail, i.e. a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 5):

For `bare_journal_comsoc.tex` with `IEEEtran.cls`, the following works.

Put this after `\maketitle`

```
\thispagestyle{empty} %--to make title page number less
\pagestyle{empty}    % -- to make other pages number less.
```

If you put

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

then, numbers are still coming but at the center of the footer as in IEEE published papers.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Thanks for your first answer here. Here you could find helpful information for you [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and have fun with LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, avoiding the `conference` document-class option (just as another member commented above) and replacing it will `comsoc` will start generating page numbers.