# Force insert page numbers - IFAC conference Latex template

Tags: page-numbering

Within the [IFAC latex template](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/view), I wish to forcefully show the page numbers on the document, even though I know I am not supposed to do that. Could anyone kindly help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52785/184389) gives the way to do it. However, instead of placing the commands after `\maketitle`, place them after `\end{frontmatter}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\begin{document}` and `\thispagestyle{plain}` after `\end{frontmatter}`.

Remember to remove the two instructions when submitting the paper.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I couldn't believe it was that simple. I spent more than an hour trying to edit stuff in the .cls file