# Show page numbers in IEEEtran document class

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, ieeetran

I'm writing a scientific article. I found that the best option is to use the `IEEEtran` document class:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

But in this document the command

```
\pagenumbering
```

doesn't seem to do anything, and i cannot enumerate the pages.

How can i show page numbers in this document class?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) With a quick search on this same website, it is easy to find that your question has already been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52729/forcing-page-numbers-with-ieeetran).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\pagenumbering` macro does not actually force page numbers to be typeset. It only does two things. First, it governs the *style* of the page numbers, i.e, it determines whether the page numbers are typeset as arabic numerals, lowercase or uppercase Roman numerals, lowercase or uppercase alphabetic letters, etc. (Well, there is also `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, which does render the page "numbers" invisible.) Second, `\pagenumbering` resets the `page` counter variable to zero.

The recognized options for `\pagenumbering` in the standard LaTeX document classes are `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, and `Alph`, The `alphalph` package provides two additional arguments: `alphalph` and `AlphAlph`, for numbering with two alphabetic characters, increasing the number of permissible page numbers from 26 to 26*26=576. Other packages and document classes may provided additional styles.

The `IEEEtran` document class provides the following instructions (cf. lines 5631 ff. in `IEEEtran.cls`):

```
%% SET UP THE DEFAULT PAGESTYLE
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

The `headings` page style, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel, places page numbers (and other pieces of information) in the header row.

If the `IEEEtran` document class is loaded with the option `conference`, the macro `\ifCLASSOPTIONconference` evaluates to 'true' and the following lines of code also get executed (cf. lines 2471 ff. in `IEEEtran.cls`):

```
% turn off headers for conferences
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
\fi
```

That's why no page numbers are typeset if the `conference` class option is set.

So, what to do if you *do* want to show page numbers?

- If you wish to show the page numbers centered in the *footer* of the document, simply insert (a) the instruction

  ```
  \pagestyle{plain}
  ```

  in the preamble and (b) `\thispagestyle{plain}` immediately after `\maketitle`. (That's the instruction you'll find in several answers given to [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52729/5001).)
- If, however, you wish to typeset the page number at the left-hand edge of the *header line*, you should execute

  ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand\@oddhead{\thepage}
   \makeatother
  ```

  If you need to show a page number on the very first page, I would recommend that you run `\thispagestyle{plain}` after `\maketitle`, as it's customary to leave the header row blank on the first page of a document (or major division such as "chapter").